# spring boot Mockito mock null exception

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, mocking, mockito, junit4

I want to mock one method in another method, but always got null point exception in the object I mock, exception in line 40.

Any ideas will appreciate!!!

[image]

[image]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.util.InteractionLogUtilTest.setUp(InteractionLogUtilTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Better provide the code as text instead of screenshots. Also the stacktrace would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

On top

`@RunWith(Spring4JunitRunner.class)`

should be

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

It should be working.

Thank You

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I tried MockitoJUnitRunner, still the same NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I overlooked. Please put in setup method at start.

```
Public void setup()

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Comment: You should edit your previous answer, insteead of posting another one...

Comment: Hi, thanks guys. MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) doesn't work for me.  Finally I just did a unit test instead of integrating test, using a constructor to inject the dependency, instead of autowire annotation

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@Mock` on createCustomerInteraction you should probably have 
used `@Spy`.

`Mockito.spy(...)` is normally called on an already existing object (which usually is not a mock). You instead used it on a class.

I am not sure whether you actually intended to override the Mock (the one you made by using the Annotation) in the `setUp` method, but I think that was just another mistake you made. (There should not be a need for that if you use the proper annotation anyway).

Edit:
There is another possibility for the NPE and that is that instead of `createCustomerInteraction` being null, is actually the `transaction`.
You didn`t declare an @Mock for transaction, so if it is not initialized anywhere else, its probably null.

Comment: This one doesn't work, if i spy one method A, another method B in A needs to spy, finally after I spy almost every method, the last method has  variable whose value is from .yml configuration, which is null. Anyway, it works now, using unit test instead if integration test.  It's caused by poor application structure, which include external jar dependency files, which make Junit test quite difficult.

Comment: What you are saying sound rather confused to me. If you end up spying almost every method you are probably doing some wrong and/or have yet to understand the concept of spying. I wouldnt call a mockito test an integration test anyway, since you are stripping things away instead of integrating them.

Comment: I also feel confused, if it's just common case, the question won't appear here

Comment: I justed noticed another thing I overlooked, which also might be responsible for the NPE. You didn`t declare an @Mock for transaction. -- Anyway if you are willing to give Mockito another go and it still does not work just ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
doReturn(createCustomerInteractionResponse).when(createCustomerInteraction).yourMethod(yourArguments);
```